# Grails 2.3 - New Sample Project not working

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

i created a new grails 2.3 sample project.

It is giving error while refresh-dependencies or run-app

```
Loading Grails 2.3.0.M1
| Configuring classpath
| Error org.sonatype.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies for [xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 (compile), org.grails:grails-bootstrap:jar:2.3.0.M1 (compile), org.grails:grails-scripts:jar:2.3.0.M1 (compile), org.grails.plugins:tomcat:zip:7.0.39 (compile)]
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:258)
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:308)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.maven.aether.AetherDependencyManager.collectDependencies(AetherDependencyManager.groovy:389)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.maven.aether.AetherDependencyManager.resolve(AetherDependencyManager.groovy:262)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy:505)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure16.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:756)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure16.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:750)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings.getBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:655)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.ClasspathConfigurer.getClassLoaderUrls(ClasspathConfigurer.java:107)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.ClasspathConfigurer.configuredClassLoader(ClasspathConfigurer.java:70)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.initializeState(GrailsScriptRunner.java:618)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.initializeState(GrailsScriptRunner.java:601)
| Error     at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.ensureInitialized(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:127)
| Error     at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:141)
| Error     at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:126)
| Error     at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:89)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
| Error Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1
| Error     at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:296)
| Error     at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:240)
| Error     ... 48 more
| Error Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact xalan:serializer:pom:2.7.1 from/to grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): null to http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.pom
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
| Error     at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
| Error     ... 51 more
| Error Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact xalan:serializer:pom:2.7.1 from/to grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): null to http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.pom
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:1546)
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:1537)
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:1035)
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.get(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:409)
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:457)
| Error     ... 54 more
| Error Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: null to http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.pom
| Error     at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:95)
| Error     at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:381)
| Error     at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.addListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:148)
| Error     at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:945)
| Error     at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:776)
| Error     at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:484)
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:891)
| Error     at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.get(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:402)
| Error     ... 55 more
| Error Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
| Error     at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:85)
| Error     at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:597)
| Error     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:140)
```

| Error     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:103)
| Error     at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:60)
| Error     at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleDownstream(HttpClientCodec.java:82)
| Error     at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleDownstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:115)
| Error     at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:541)
| Error     at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:210)
| Error     at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:227)
| Error     at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:188)
| Error     at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:902)
| Error     ... 59 more

And my BuildConfig.groovy is this:

> ```
>     grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container
>       compliance (2.5 or 3.0) grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
>     grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
>     grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
>     grails.project.work.dir = "target/work" grails.project.target.level =
>      1.6 grails.project.source.level = 1.6 //grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
>
>      forkConfig = [maxMemory: 1024, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm:
>      256] grails.project.fork = [    test: forkConfig, // configure
>      settings for the test-app JVM    run: forkConfig, // configure
>      settings for the run-app JVM    war: forkConfig, // configure settings
>      for the run-war JVM    console: forkConfig // configure settings for
>      the Swing console JVM ]
>
>      grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
>      grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
> ```
>
> System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "10.20.30.40");
>     System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
>
> ```
> // inherit Grails' default dependencies
> inherits("global") {
>     // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
>     // excludes 'ehcache'
> }
> log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
> checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
> legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility
>
> repositories {
>     inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
>
>     grailsPlugins()
>     grailsHome()
>     mavenLocal()
>     grailsCentral()
>     mavenCentral()
>     // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
>     //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
>     //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
>     //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
>     // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
> }
>
> plugins {
>     // plugins for the build system only
>     build ":tomcat:7.0.39"
>
>     // plugins for the compile step
>     compile ":scaffolding:1.0.0"
>     compile ':cache:1.0.1'
>
>     // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
>     runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.M3" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
>     runtime ":database-migration:1.3.3"
>     runtime ":jquery:1.9.1"
>     runtime ":resources:1.2"
>     // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
>     //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
>     //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
>     //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
> } }
> ```

Comment: are you behind a proxy? have you tried passing proxy config via add-proxy command: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html

Answer (score 6):

Until they can figure out what's wrong with maven

In your BuildConfig change grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" to grails.project.dependency.resolver = "ivy"

Don't forget to refresh dependencies

Answer (score 5):

Like [user2264997](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916563/grails-2-3-new-sample-project-not-working#comment24433104_16916563) said, you can use `add-proxy` and `set-proxy` to configure the global proxy for Grails 2.3.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html

`grails add-proxy client --host=proxy-server --port=4300 
       --username=guest --password=guest`

When you run that command, grails will create `${HOME}/.grails/ProxySettings.groovy` that contains your proxy information. You can tweak the settings to your heart's content.

One thing to note is that you should not run `grails add-proxy` from the project directory because it will attempt to resolve the missing dependencies before it tries to set the proxy. I simply backed up a directory to run it.

Comment: this worked. I ran them in a separate cmd terminal. Note - if you're using GGTS you'll have to restart it for the proxy changes to work

Comment: Just a gotcha: Make sure you don't run this command from within your project's directory. Otherwise grails will try to resolve your project's dependencies first, which will fail because the proxy is not set!

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to resolve this same issue by removing my incumbent Maven cache directory ($HOME/.m2).  I haven't dug into why exactly this fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Add the Jars to the Lib folder in your App;

you can download the Jars from http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ant/7.0.42.