# error: failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan

Tags: grails, xalan

I am getting an error "failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar 2.7.1 while creating a domain class using "grails create-domain-class Employee"  command on command prompt. I am currently using Grails 2.3.7 .
Please help me to solve my Error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916563/grails-2-3-new-sample-project-not-working

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()

    mavenRepo "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    
}
```

Works perfectly for me.

Comment: This should be the right answer for the above mentioned issue. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue resolving the dependencies needed for your project.

In BuildConfig.groovy, if you have a repository that contains the dependencies, reference it like so:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    mavenRepo "http://example.:8081/this/that/other/public/"
}
```

Alternatively, try changing the dependency resolver to ivy rather than maven. I think this makes grails try to get its dependencies from it's own libraries.... I could be very wrong.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "ivy"
```

Comment: changing it to the ivy resolver fixed it for me, it's not the recommended option for the future tho

Comment: It helps me too (changing to ivy), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try  in a `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
dependencies {  
 provided('xalan:xalan:2.7.1')
}
```

and see it will help you or not !...